# Missing whitespace when printing in a loop

Tags: python

I have this strange problem when following a reference, this code:

```
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(r):
        print "",
    for c in range(10-r):
        print c,
    print ""
```

should print out something like this:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
          0 1 2 3 4 5 6
            0 1 2 3 4 5
              0 1 2 3 4
                0 1 2 3
                  0 1 2
                    0 1
                      0
```

but Instead I am getting this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
    0 1 2 3 4 5 
     0 1 2 3 4 
      0 1 2 3 
       0 1 2 
        0 1 
         0
```

Can anyone explain to me what is causing in indent on right side, it seems so simple but I have no clue what I can do to fix this?

Comment: `for c in range(r): print " ",` instead of `print "",`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Well that was simple, Could you explain to me what it was doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were printing the leading spaces incorrectly.  You were printing empty quotes (`""`) which is printing only a single space. When you do `print c`, there is a space printed after `c` is printed.  You should print `" "` instead to get the correct spacing.  This is a very subtle thing to notice.

```
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(r):
        print " ", #print it here
    for c in range(10-r):
        print c,
    print ""
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/p7nEOg)

Comment: I understand my mistake now, though If i do remove the loop it wont be the same? I'm trying to figure out how it became that shape.

Comment: a print statement followed by a comma means "print [whatever], followed by a space". So `print "",` doesn't print nothing, it prints one space.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format it just so, it might be better to just let Python do it for you instead of counting explicit and the hidden implicit spaces. See the [string formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for what `{:^19}` means and more.

```
for i in range(10):
    nums = ' '.join(str(x) for x in range(10 - i))
    #print '{:^19}'.format(nums) # reproduces your "broken" code
    print '{:>19}'.format(nums) # your desired output
```

Using the print function is a good alternative sometimes, as you can eliminate hidden spaces by setting the keyword argument `end` to an empty string:

```
from __future__ import print_function # must be at the top of the file.
# ...
print(x, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not creating *enough* indent on the left side (there is no such thing as right side indent while printing).

For every new line you want to increase the indent by **two** spaces, because you are adding a number+whitespace on the line above. `"",` automatically adds **one** whitespace (this is why there is whitespaces between the numbers). Since you need to add two, simply add a whitespace within the quotes, like this: `" ",`.

The extra whitespace is filling the space of the number in the line above. The comma in `"",` is only filling the space *between* the numbers. To clarify: `" ",` uses the same space as `c,`, two characters, while `"",` only uses one character.

Here is your code with the small fix:

```
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(r):
        print " ", # added a whitespace here for correct indent
    for c in range(10-r):
        print c,
    print ""
```